# Is it possible to force it to add particular parameter to URL when current_user is logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

These are valid path in my application

1. `foo-sample.com/communities/564?search=testing`
2. `foo-sample.com/users/484#section`
3. `foo-sample.com/codes/249`

and they could be led by these routing

1. `show_community_path(@community)`
2. `show_user_path(@user, :anchor => "section")`
3. `show_code_path(@code)`

When current_user(id is 14) is logged in, I'd like it force it to redirect to these

1. `foo-sample.com/communities/564?search=testing&que=14`
2. `foo-sample.com/users/484?user=14#section`
3. `foo-sample.com/codes/249?user=14`

What is the smartest way to make it possible?
In views, do I always need to write routing path codes separated into the cases when logged-in, and not?

Comment: What should happen if the user actually enters `foo-sample.com/codes/249?user=14` as an URL in the browser in case he's not logged in or in case he's logged in as user 42?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson nothing happens `user=14` will be ignored. It only helps to create cookie code `key=>user, value=>14`

Comment: why would you create a cookie on each page? i don't think that you are describing your problem well. what do you want to achieve? there is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @phoet I'm trying to save a cookie of inviter(Existing User)'s id when a guest accesses to `foo-sample.com/something?user=14` then if the guest signs up, this cookie will be saved to guest's particular column via hidden field. So inviters(Existing User) can provide any URL which contains his id in URL parameter just like `user=14`

Comment: so usually you would create a "landingpage" for this where you can read the referrer id from the url, write a cookie or use the session to store the information and use that info on the signup.